Style element based on number of children the child has
I know I can style an element in CSS based on how many children it has with the :has() pseudo-class:
.wrapper:has(> :last-child:nth-child(3)) { 
  background-color: red;
}

However, in my case, the HTML looks like this:
<div class='list'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <span>Element1</span>
    <span>Element2</span>
    <span>Element3</span>
  </div>
</div>

I want to style the list class dependent on how many elements there are.

Do you mean total number of elements, the children, the grandchildren, the great grandchildren….Is there any limit to the depth?

.wrapper:has(> :last-child:nth-child(3)) this selector probably (I'm not able to check right now) won't work, you may need to rewrite it as .wrapper:has(& > :last-child:nth-child(3)), though this may depend on the browser and/or OS in use.

Does .list:has(.wrapper:first-child > :last-child:nth-child(3)){background-color: red;} give what is wanted? (i.e. is .wrapper always the first child? - if not remove that first-child).

I have reopened the question, this is not really a duplicate. The OP is asking about the grand-children, as far as I can tell, not really about the children.

@AHaworth I believe that your comment is the answer, but OP should clarify what is really asked

@vals the duplicate is still relevant because the selector structure is 90% the same. We only need to remove the > to consider nested childs.

This snippet colors the background of .list depending on how many children .wrapper has. It has added that it wants .wrapper to be the first-child of .list as that's what it is in the given code.


.list:has(.wrapper:first-child > :last-child:nth-child(3)) {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class='list'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <span>Element1</span>
    <span>Element2</span>
    <span>Element3</span>
  </div>
</div>



Note: if any old wrapper inside list is what is required then delete :first-child

Hey Guys
I just realized, that the last answer runs in Crome but not in Firefox!!!

What version of Firefox? FF was late in implementing :has but should be OK now.

It's OK on my Firefox (124.0.2) on Windows10.

Your right... I m still on Firefox 115.9 on my old machine

.list:has(:last-child:nth-child(3)) would also do the job for his html structure.
